# Completely transparent UITabBar in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, transparent

I'm trying to make my tabBar transparent, I've searched but all I found was articles resulting in partly and not fully transparent tabBars and some were for IOS 5, etc.

I would like to accomplish this as seen in Sketch 3:

[image]

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

I thought of doing this:

```
    // Make the tabBar transparent
self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = YES;
```

but that result wasn't exactly perfect:

[image]

Really appreciate help!:)

Sincerely,
Erik

**Update**

```
// Make the tabBar transparent
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = YES;
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have you tried the `barTintColor`?

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Same result with the code I put in my updated question :/ - I put this code in the viewWillAppear method, is that correct?

Comment: @Erik `viewWillAppear:` is too late. Try putting it in your AppDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and see if that helps.

Comment: @JohannesFagrenkrug unfortunately same result with the code in my update written in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: Man you save a lot of my time.

Comment: This worked but it still has a black line at the top of the tab bar, any ideas how to get rid of this?

Comment: I used this in combination with Lior's answer, setShadowImage was the trick to get the black line to go away.

Answer (score 32):

**Swift 3.0**

... call this code in the AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
let tabBar = UITabBar.appearance()
tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

The result will be a transparent background for every UITabBar.

Comment: After so many tries of different things and solutions around the internet, this made the tabbar 'translucent' but now it feels it is too translucent and has no blur to it at all. I believe its the tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage() that causes this. Any additional help that can generate that nice blur effect instead of complete transparency?

Answer (score 6):

You need to subclass the UITabBarController and in the `viewdidload:` you should put this code:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 1.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
UIImage *transparentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.tabBar setBackgroundImage:transparentImage];
[self.tabBar setShadowImage:transparentImage];    
//    self.tabBar.alpha = 0.0;
```

Comment: I didn't use a subclass, but `setShadowImage` was the secret to my problem, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using the following code:

```
let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
...    
tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = .clear
tabBarController.tabBar.isTranslucent = true
            
tabBarController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
tabBarController.edgesForExtendedLayout = .all
```