# Fully transparent and floating like UItabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

how can I make the UItabbar fully transparent and floating like shown on the screenshot? I would like to avoid the multiple buttons solutions because UItabbar provide a nice method to display multiple view controller. Thanks all

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Completely transparent UITabBar in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279478/completely-transparent-uitabbar-in-ios-8)

Answer (score 0):

A simple search would have shown you this,

```
tabBar.barTintColor = .clear
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```